# combing include php files

Tags: php

I have separate php files. I have a master file that I use by include these files like

```
    /include '1.php';
    /include '2.php';
   / include '3.php';
```

Now I want to combine this 3 file to one php file.How can I use them because in my master code there are 3 conditions,like condition 1 uses file 1.php condition  2 uses file 2.php and so on
thanx

Comment: if you want to make one file, whatever is in files 1 2 and 3 need to be prepended to the beginning of your master file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can write your code this way

```
<?php
    if(condition1) include('file1.php');           

    else if(condition2) include('file2.php');          

         else include('file3.php'); 
?>
```

you can either write this

```
<?php
    if(condition1) include('file1.php');           

    if(condition2) include('file2.php');           

    if(condition3) include('file3.php');               

?>
```

good work !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to combine the files into one, but still use the conditions of the master file, simply include the code from the include file inside the same condition that you used to chose to select the include file.  If you had:

```
if(A){
    include "1.php";
}
if(B){
    include "2.php";
}
if(C){
    include "3.php";
}
```

Instead use:

```
if(A){
    //contents of 1.php here
}
if(B){
    //contents of 2.php here
}
if(C){
    //contents of 3.php here
}
```